# Excel formula help

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet with 2 columns

```
Contact Status  Max Probability
80-Opp          Closed Won
0-NC              Closed Won
40-Pending       30-Connect
10-Working      20- Engagement
80-Opportunity  30-Connect
40-Pending        10- Engagement
```

I need to check if the no in contact status ie the numeric value before '-' is less than numeric value in max probabilty before '-', then i need the whole value of max probability update the contact status field

For eg.

```
 10-Working     20- Engagement
```

10-Working should be replaced by 20- Engagement

OR

We can have 20- Engagement in a new column if the above mentioned conditioned is satisfied, if replacing  the contact Status column is difficult
How can achieve this?

Comment: DO you want a macro to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little macro will do the trick. Just change `Row` to the starting row and `ColA/B` to the two columns you want to use.

Note that `GetNum` returns `-1` if there is no number at the start which, in this implementation, means no copying. It was unclear what you wanted to do tith `Closed Won` so I chose the safest option. If you do want it copied, just return a huge number instead of `-1`.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetNum(s As String) As Integer
    If Mid(s, 1, 1) < "0" Or Mid(s, 1, 1) > "9" Then
        GetNum = -1
    Else
        GetNum = Val(s)
    End If
End Function

Sub Macro1()
    Dim Row As String
    Dim ColA As String
    Dim ColB As String

    ColA = "A"
    ColB = "B"
    Row = "2"
    While Range(ColA & Row).Value <> ""
        If GetNum(Range(ColA & Row).Value) < GetNum(Range(ColB & Row).Value) Then
            Range(ColA & Row).Value = Range(ColB & Row).Value
        End If
        Row = CStr(Val(Row) + 1)
    Wend
End Sub
```

This was tested on:

[image]

to generate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This macro will do:

```
Sub a()
ColumnContSt=1
ColumnMaxProb=2
i = 1
While (Cells(i, 2) <> "")
    colB = Cells(i, ColumnMaxProb)
    colA = Cells(i, ColumnContSt)
    posB = InStr(1, colB, "-")
    posA = InStr(1, colA, "-")
    If (posB <> 0 And posA <> 0) Then
        intColB = CInt(Mid(colB, 1, posB - 1))
        intColA = CInt(Mid(colA, 1, posA - 1))

        If (intColA < intColB) Then
            Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Just change   **ColumnContSt = 1 and  ColumnMaxProb = 2**  for your actual column **NUMBERS**  ie. A=1, B=2, etc.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

If you are flexible about the actual data, the easiest way to do this is to make two columns (can be hidden in some far away sheet):

```
0   NC
10  Engagement
30  Connect
...
```

And then use `VLOOKUP(CELL_WITH_PROBABILITY, REGION_WITH_TABLE, 2, true)`.  So if you put my small 3 element table in the upper corner of a sheet and probability in C1, it'd look like `VLOOKUP(A1:B3, C1, 2, true)`